# Properties don't get initialized in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, declared-property

I'm developing for iOS 7 but I still have to manually write getters otherwise my properties just don't get initialized. I tried to manually synthesize those properties, even though that shouldn't be needed anymore, but that doesn't do it.

In my view controller below, I use the property `motionTracker`, which never gets initialized. I have the same issue with all my projects, so I know it's a misunderstanding on my part.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TracksMotion.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startRecording;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *stopRecording;

@property (strong, nonatomic) TracksMotion *motionTracker;
@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize motionTracker = _motionTracker;

- (void)startMyMotionDetect
{
    [self.motionTracker startsTrackingMotion];
}

@end
```

The `motionTracker` has a public API for the method `startsTrackingMotion` so I don't know why this doesn't work.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>

@interface TracksMotion : NSObject

- (void)startsTrackingMotion;

- (void)stopTrackingMotion;

@property (strong, nonatomic) CMMotionManager *motionManager;

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties / instance variables *are not* magically initialized for you. When you say:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) TracksMotion *motionTracker;
```

... you are just reserving memory space for an instance variable (and generating a getter and a setter method through `@synthesize` or autosynthesis). There is no actual TracksMotion object there *until you put one there*. You must write code to do that. You must *create or obtain* a TracksMotion instance and assign it to `self.motionTracker` at some point, presumably early in the life of `self` (in this case, that's a ViewController instance). Until you run code that does that, `self.motionTracker` is nil.

(It is possible that you are being confused because it looks like outlets *are* automatically initialized. For example, you've got `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *startRecording;` And sure enough, `self.startRecording` is a button. But that's because the nib-loading process does for you the very thing I'm saying you must do: it makes a button from the storyboard or .xib file, and assigns it to this instance variable.)

Comment: Basically, do self.motionTracker = [[TrackerMotion alloc]init];  I thought that this wasn't even required, I thought that the property would get created when needed, just by using self.property. Thanks!

Comment: @BillCapelli Unless that's not the designated initializer.