# NSMutableString init issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I have an issue with NSMutablestring. When i use it without override my class init method it doesn't work.

my interface code:

```
@interface Topic : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *description;

@end
```

If I created an object with this class then tried to assign a string to the "title", its NSLog prints Null!

This is my code when I'm trying to use it:

```
Topic *myTopic = [[Topic alloc] init];
[myTopic.title appendString:@"Hello World"];
```

To avoid this problem I have to override my Topic class init method and add this line:

```
self.title = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
```

Any idea?

EDIT: this line should initialize my properties and methods right (without overriding the init method)?

```
Topic *myTopic = [[Topic alloc] init];
```

Thanks,

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: You have to override the `init` method and allocate your strings or allocate them elsewhere manually... They don't magically initialize themselves.

Comment: Please, please, please at least study some elementary Objective-C tutorials.

Comment: i think its enough to initialize my methods and properties with this line (without overriding the init method):     Topic *myTopic = [[Topic alloc] init];

Comment: possible duplicate of [Properties don't get initialized in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439563/properties-dont-get-initialized-in-ios-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first create your object, the title object is nil. You must initialize the title object before you can append anything to it.

```
self.title = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

You should set this in the appropriate place - e.g., viewDidLoad on a view controller.

See Tommy's comment below for why you wouldn't want to do this in the init method itself.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, and I doubt this is the reason for the down vote but: you should never call a setter within your `init`. You don't know whether a subclass has overridden it.

Comment: This information is already contained in the original post.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have specified.

Comment: If i have to initialize every property in my Class, what is the idea behind writing: MyClass *class = [[MyClass alloc] init]

Comment: That creates an instance of the class. But it's still up to you to create and configure any objects that your class declares as properties. You may want to assign initial values, or to leave certain properties empty — neither the language nor the framework can accurately infer your intent just from the declarations in your interface.

Comment: Ahmed, you might find it helpful to check out this basic overview of creating a class in ObjC: http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/classes.html